# Number of Subsets with $n$ elements from set $x$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

How can I determine the number of subsets that has n elements in them while excluding all other subsets ?

Suppose I have X={A,B,C,D,E}

how many subsets can I have with exactly 3 elements such as {A,B,C}.. etc? 2 to the power of 5 would yield the total possible number of all subsets that can be formed from X

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**: How many ways can you [choose](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination) $3$ out of $6$ elements? (P.S.: There are actually $2^6$ subsets of $X$ as given.)

Comment: sometimes its too simple that I just can't see it tho it's staring me in the face, thank you so much! i figured it out

Answer (score 0):

write a subset as a string of $0$'s/$1$'s so that, e.g.
$$
\{A,B,F\} \rightarrow 110001 \\
\{B,D,E,F\} \rightarrow 010111
$$
can you see that each subset corresponds to a unique number in the range $0$ to $31 = 2^6-1$
this generalises in an obvious way to any finite cardinality, and corresponds to the important fact concerning the power set of a set $S$, namely:
$$
|\mathfrak{P}(S)| = 2^{|S|}
$$
if you want the number of 3-element subsets then you require the number of choosing 3 zeroes and 3 ones, i.e. $\binom{|S|}{3}$

Comment: that's quite an interesting answer, thank you!